# calculate radius of two circle given the distance between their radius??

Tags: geometry, circles, area

Given two circles $A$ and $B$ with distance from their radius $d$ , is it possible to calculate the radius of the circles? If yes, how?

[image: two circle with their distance]

What if we add a $3^{rd}$ circle $C$ , with distance $d_2$ from center of $B$ and $C$ and given that $C$ is half of $A$ i.e $ r_a = 2r_c$ , is it mathematically possible? [image: 3 circles]

Comment: This is not clear.  In the first diagram, are you saying that the distance from $A$ to $B$, presumably the two centers, is $d$?  If so, then that is not enough to determine the two radii.  All you know is that $r_A+r_B=d$.

Comment: In first case, you cannot.  You can draw many circles with different radii meeting the distance d condition. In 2nd case, you can find it.

Comment: thanks @MathLover and lulu , i suspected that the first one was lacking information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, the only restriction you have is $r_A + r_B = d$. There are infinitely many possibilities for the two radii so you cannot determine them

In the second example, notice that $d = r_A + r_B = 2r_C + r_B$.
Therefore, $d - d_2 = r_C$.

Now, that you know $r_C$, you can compute $r_A = 2r_c$ and $r_B = d_2 - r_C$.